# Search scope for list returning 0 items

Tags: search, sharepoint-online, search-results, search-scope

I'm trying to add a search for a list of user manuals.

[I was following this link's instructions](http://www.bentedder.com/create-a-search-scope-for-a-sharepoint-2010-list-or-library/)

And I have the scope set up as,

```
Scope Rule Type:    Web Address
Web Address:        Folder: https://siteurl/Lists/User%20Manuals/
Behavior:           Require
```

But after the server does it's scope refresh, I get an item count of 0 and a total count of 0. Also, when I test the search, nothing is returned.

I can't look at crawl logs because this is through SharePoint Online and I don't have access to the Central Administration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try the address without %20, so with "https://siteurl/Lists/User Manuals/"

Comment: I tried that with no luck. I also made another generic list called test and created a new scope set up to look in the folder "https://siteurl/Lists/test" and that's not giving me anything either.

Comment: Actually, it looks like it was just an environment issue. I tried the scope in our production environment and everything worked!